# Comments of deleted/undeleted answer are missing on network profile

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-answers, network-profile, undelete

I have noticed that on my Stack Exchange network profile, some (2) comments missing that are part of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16168855/83039) that was deleted and then undeleted.

The workflow of the question was:

1. Answer posted
2. Comment posted
3. Answer deleted
4. Answer edited
5. Answer undeleted
6. Comment posted
7. Answer edited

**Comments of stackoverflow**
[image: Comments on stackoverflow]

**Comments of stackexchange**
[image: Comments on stackexchange]