# Missing item in inbox

Tags: bug, global-inbox, comment-replies

There seems to be an inconsistency in my inbox. There has been a message from a user (under the form of a @reply comment) that I can see under the post and in the "responses" tab in my profile, but it is not showing up in my inbox:

[image]

It seems the post in question has been quickly deleted, then undeleted (see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/430574/timeline), so this is probably what caused the issue.

Comment: Also duplicate of [Comments of deleted/undeleted answer are missing on network profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177855/comments-of-deleted-undeleted-answer-are-missing-on-network-profile)